# A sufficient and necessary condition of Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on $(-R,R)$. Prove that
$f(x)$ can be expanded as its Taylor series at the point $x=0$ over the interval $(-R,R)$ if and only if there exists a positive function $M(r)$ $(0 \le r < R)$, such that
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)| \le \frac{M(r)n!}{(r-|x|)^{n+1}}
$$
for $n \ge 0$ and $|x| < r < R$.

Letˊs try the sufficiency.Suppose $f(x)$ can be expanded as itˊs Taylor series at $x=0$, that is $$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}y^n$$
, the series converges uniformly and absolutely for $|y-x| \lt R-|x|$, hence $$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(y-x)^n$$ converges uniformly and absolutely for $|y-x|<R-|x|$. Then 
$$ |f^{(n)}(x)| \le \frac{n!}{|r-x|^{n+1}}\sum_{k \ne n}\frac{|f^{(k)}(r)|}{k!}|r-x|^{k+1} \le \frac{M(r)n!}{(r-|x|)^{n+1}}$$, where
$$ M(r):=\sum_{k \ne n}\frac{|f^{(k)}(r)|}{k!}|r-x|^{k+1} $$.

But the necessity seems hard to prove.

Comment: Can you please show your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: @egreg I tried but failed.Now I will try again.

Comment: @egreg Are you still there, could you please come and see my proof?

Comment: That seems a promising start +1

Comment: @egreg I know that you are a mathematician working on algebra, could you please help me with this analytic problem?

Comment: @egreg It seems that Cauchy remainder term is the only thing need to consider.Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is suffice to show $\forall r'>0$, the Taylor series converges to $f(r')$. Find $r$ such that $0 <r'<r<R$. The intergral remainder $$T(n,r')=\int_{0}^{r'}(r'-t)^{n}\frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{n!}dt$$
Together with the inequality $|f^{(n+1)}(t)| \le \frac{M(r)(n+1)!}{(r-|t|)^{n+2}}$,
$$|T(n,r')|\leq(n+1)M(r)\int_{0}^{r'}\frac{(r'-t)^n}{(r-t)^{n+2}}dt\leq\frac{M(r)(n+1)}{(1+p)^n}C, p>0$$
Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}T(n,r')=0$$